# How do I import UMD in ESM?

Tags: ecmascript-6, umd

I have a UMD library and the following works in commonjs...

```
global.window = global;
var DoSomething = require("../dist/sce-umd.js").DoSomething;
(function(){
    var instance = new DoSomething();
    instance.doSomethingElse();
})()
```

I am trying to do the same thing with ESM like...

```
(()=>{
    // Needed for UMD
    global.window = global;
    import("../dist/sce-umd.js").then((OtherThing)=>{

        console.log("This is the next level");
        const other = new OtherThing();
        other.doSomethingElse();
    });
})();
```

But I get...

> TypeError: OtherThing is not a constructor

I also tried `new OtherThing.DoSomething()` but I get...

> TypeError: OtherThing.DoSomething is not a constructor

Comment: I'm guessing you need to write it like `import { default as OtherThing } from '../dist/sce-umd.js'` but not sure. Can you show how your UMD module exports itself?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `.default` prop of the returned module, like so below:

```js
import("./some-umd.js").then((myModule)=>{
    const myThing = myModule.default;  <---- This is the key 
    // ... do what you need with myThing
});
```

In normal import, you do the following if `import { default as myThing } from './some-umd.js';` doesn't work:

```js
import myModule from './some-umd.js';

const myThing = myModule.default;
```